Problem with Flycheck and the C++ ranges library
I'm setting up Emacs for writing (modern) C++ code on my machine. I configured lsp-mode and Flycheck, but there is something that isn't working.
I generated a compile_commands.json issuing cmake before opening my main.cc with Emacs, but if I #include the ranges library the all my Flycheck "checkers" (lsp, c/c++ clang and c/c++-gcc) can't locate the library.
My clangd version is 19.
What can I do? I found almost nothing on the web about that.

With lsp-mode, clangd server takes priority over flycheck, and flycheck
becomes lsp's error display engine. You do not need to configure flycheck in any
way; all configurations should be part of your CMakeLists.txt file.
The only odd case is when you disconnect lsp, and you maybe need to
configure: flycheck-clang-language-standard, flycheck-clang-executable,
similar for included headers and variables with -gcc- instead -clang-).

It would be helpful to specify what is your OS and Emacs version and where is located  your compiler.

On top of what's already mentioned, please post a reproducible example of your problem. For example, does it happen if you just write test.cpp and run lsp there?
